# Hide/show, switch between divs using only DOM API

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make several divs and switch between them when different buttons are clicked.

Each div will hold something different, for instance the main div is visible on load, the rest are hidden and depending on which button you click you open that div while at the same time hiding the current div. Basically switching between divs smoothly without delay and such.

Below is what I got to, I have 2 divs, the main div is visible from get go, while the other is hidden in my css and when I click on button it displays, but my first div is still visible and I have to click button to make it hidden.

My question is how do I go about making an efficient if statement to make one div appear/visible by clicking a button while the current  disappears and joins dosens other that are hidden until I click on their button?

I don't understand JavaScript very well and I want to understand how to do it so **no JQuery** please :)

And I'm asking about how to do this with divs because I don't know if there is any other way to do it, if there is then please share :)

Thanks

```
// Div One
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('button');
mainDiv.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('newpost');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
};

// Div Two  
var upgradesDiv = document.getElementById('button2');
upgradesDiv.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('UpgradesDiv');
    if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

Comment: Please write a function and pass the div into it. Duplicate logic...

Comment: jQuery also has a `$.hide()` and `$.show()` function.

Comment: "no jQuery please" is mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for help guys, I  appreciate it. and I'll remember $.hide()/show for when I become a full fledged... half fledged coder :) thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not fully understand ultimately what you're trying to do. But given your example, you could wrap your `div` tags in a container and pass some indentifier to your function:

**JS**

```
function toggleDiv(target){

   var div = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByTagName("div");

   if (target == 1) {
      div[0].style.display = 'none';
      div[1].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      div[0].style.display = 'block';
      div[1].style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="button" onclick="toggleDiv(0)">one</div>
<div id="button2" onclick="toggleDiv(1)">two</div>

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="newpost"></div>
   <div id="UpgradesDiv"></div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6t0n3g1x/2/)

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, within my Javascript capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

## Regular; plain-old-javascript way:

```js
function onComplete() {
  hide(getById('newPost'));
  hide(getById('upgrades'));
  
  clickAndToggle('button1', ['newPost']);
  clickAndToggle('button2', ['upgrades']);
}

function clickAndToggle(buttonId, toggleTargetIds) {
  var mainDiv = getById(buttonId);
  mainDiv.onclick = function() {
    toggleTargetIds.forEach(function(targetId) {
      toggle(getById(targetId));
    });
  };
}

function getById(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
function toggle(el) {
  window[!isVisible(el) ? 'show' : 'hide'].call(undefined, el);
}
function hide(el) {
  el.style.display = 'none';
}
function show(el) {
  el.style.display = '';
}
function isVisible(el) {
  return el.style.display !== 'none' && el.style.visibility !== 'hidden';
}

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState;
  if (state == 'complete') {
    onComplete();
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Button #1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Button #2" />
<br />

<div id="newPost">New Post!</div>
<div id="upgrades">Upgrades!</div>
```

## jQuery way

You can use `$.hide()` and `$.show()` to toggle visibility.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#newPost').hide();
  $('#upgrades').hide();
  
  clickAndToggle('#button1', ['#newPost']);
  clickAndToggle('#button2', ['#upgrades']);

  function clickAndToggle(buttonId, toggleTargetIds) {
    $(buttonId).click(function() {
      $.each(toggleTargetIds, function(idx, targetId) {
        //if(!($(targetId).is(":visible"))){$(targetId).show();}else{$(targetId).hide();}
        $(targetId).toggle();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="button1" value="Button #1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Button #2" />
<br />

<div id="newPost">New Post!</div>
<div id="upgrades">Upgrades!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for effort :) but when I push button 2, I want div associated with button 1 to disappear and same for button 2. I got it now though thanks :=)

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems the most straightforward way of doing this:

```
var first = 'newpost';
var currentDiv = document.getElementById(first);
function addDivToggle(buttonId, divId)
{
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    var newDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        currentDiv.style.display = 'none';
        newDiv.style.display = '';
        currentDiv = newDiv;
    });
}
addDivToggle('button1', 'newpost');
addDivToggle('button2', 'UpgradesDiv');
```

Here i'm assuming that 'newpost' is already visible, and the other divs are hidden.

Comment: Your code doesn't go thrue,  the bracket is... "intercepted" by the parenthesis    button.addEventListener('onclick', function. I tried but couldn't figure out the problem. thanks anywyas :) effort appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but note that when adding a 'click' event using `addEventListener`, the event type is `'click'` , and not `'onclick'`

Comment: Oh i figured out what you mean, i missed the closing parenthesis of the addEventListener call. Fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

```
// The doClick() functions does what onClick() is supposed to do when clicked manually.
    // Div One
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById('button');
    mainDiv.onclick = function() {
        var div = document.getElementById('newpost');
        if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
            div.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            div.style.display = 'block';
        }

      // add this function call
      upgradesDiv.doClick();
    };

    // Div Two  
    var upgradesDiv = document.getElementById('button2');
    upgradesDiv.onclick = function() {
        var div = document.getElementById('UpgradesDiv');
        if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
            div.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            div.style.display = 'none';
        }

      // add this function call
      mainDiv.doClick();
    };
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make the previous div hidden,  automatically, that was what i was looking for, while one div becomes visible the other goes invisible, but thanks for help :=)